# In WebStorm, how to use live templates in .txt files?

Tags: webstorm, intellij-13

I keep a "notes.txt" file in all my WebStorm projects.

How can I use Insert Live Template (<kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>), Surround With Live Template (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + J</kbd>), Surround With (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd>) in a .txt file?

Also, how can I create a Live Templates **Context** for a particular file suffix?

For instance, in my notes.txt file, I'd like to surround The Selection with

- `[]` and
- `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use Insert Live Template (`Ctrl + J`), Surround With Live Template (`Ctrl + Alt + J`), Surround With (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) in a .txt file?

Use `Other` context

[image]

---

> Also, how can I create a Live Templates Context for a particular file suffix?

As ordinary IDE user (via some GUI) -- no way (such functionality is absent). Only via custom plugin.

---

> For instance, in my notes.txt file, I'd like to surround The Selection with
>
> - [] and
> - ()

You do not need Live Templates for this.

All what you need is `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Surround selection on typing quote or brace`.

But if you insist on using Live Templates -- use `Other` context (see screenshot above -- that live template does just that)

Comment: Thanks, L.O.. I really like the Smart Keys option. It works GREAT.